# C++ Interview preparation questions - Find the maximum sum of subarray in array

Tags: c++, interview-questions

I am currently prepping for C++ interview question, by answering [some I found on the internet](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sum-of-lengths-of-non-overlapping-subarrays/0). I don't think my solution is the best, but on the other hand, I am not sure what else would be a better solution, which is why I guess hearing other people's opinion would be great.

Question being:

> Given an array of `N` elements, you are required to find the maximum sum
>   of lengths of all non-overlapping subarrays with `K` as the maximum
>   element in the subarray.

Example:

```
Input : arr[] = {2, 1, 4, 9, 2, 3, 8, 3, 4} 
        k = 4
Output : 5
{2, 1, 4} => Length = 3
{3, 4} => Length = 2
So, 3 + 2 = 5 is the answer
```

Here is my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

  std::random_device rd;  
  std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,9);

  int arr[10];

  int  k = distribution(gen);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
      arr[i] = distribution(gen);;
      std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "K: " << k << std::endl; 

  std::vector<int> start_index;
  std::vector<int> end_index;
  std::vector<int> sum;

    for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        int subarray_sum = 0;  
        if(arr[i] <= k)
        {
            start_index.push_back(i);
            subarray_sum += arr[i];
            ++i;
            while(arr[i] <= k && i<10) 
            {
                subarray_sum += arr[i];
                ++i;
            }
            end_index.push_back(i-1);
            sum.push_back(subarray_sum);
            std::cout << "sum: " << subarray_sum << std::endl; 
        }
    }

  std::cout << "length of sums: " << sum.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "number of start_index: " << start_index.size() << std::endl; 
  std::cout << "number of end_index: " << end_index.size() << std::endl; 

  std::cout << "-------------Compute max subarray_sum length-----------------" << std::endl; 
  if(sum.size() > 1)
  {
    std::vector<int>::iterator iterator1 = std::max_element(sum.begin(),sum.end());
    int position1 = iterator1 - sum.begin();
    std::cout << position1 << std::endl; 

    int length1 = end_index[position1]- start_index[position1]+1; //+1 because they don't zero-index

    sum.erase(sum.begin() + position1);
    start_index.erase(start_index.begin() + position1);
    end_index.erase(end_index.begin()+position1);

    std::cout << "length of sums: " << sum.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "number of start_index: " << start_index.size() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "number of end_index: " << end_index.size() << std::endl; 


    std::vector<int>::iterator iterator2 = std::max_element(sum.begin(),sum.end());
    int position2 = iterator2 - sum.begin();
    std::cout << position2 << std::endl; 

    int length2 = end_index[position2]- start_index[position2]+1; //+1 because they don't zero-index


    sum.erase(sum.begin() + position2);
    start_index.erase(start_index.begin() + position2);
    end_index.erase(end_index.begin()+position2);

    std::cout << "length1: " << length1 << " " << std::endl 
              << "length2: " << length2 << std::endl 
              << "legnth Sum: " << length1 + length2 << std::endl; 


  }
  else if ( sum.size() == 1)
  {
    std::vector<int>::iterator iterator1 = std::max_element(sum.begin(),sum.end());
    int position1 = iterator1 - sum.begin();
    std::cout << position1 << std::endl; 

    int length1 = end_index[position1]- start_index[position1]+1; //+1 because they don't zero-index
    std::cout << "max length sum: " << length1 << std::endl;

  }

  else
  {
    std::cout << "None fit criteria" << std::endl; 
  }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
2 3 0 7 5 8 5 5 4 8 
K: 0
sum: 0
length of sums: 1
number of start_index: 1
number of end_index: 1
-------------Compute max subarray_sum length-----------------
0
max length sum: 1
```

output:

```
2 3 4 1 8 0 0 0 1 4 
K: 4
sum: 10
sum: 5
length of sums: 2
number of start_index: 2
number of end_index: 2
-------------Compute max subarray_sum length-----------------
0
length of sums: 1
number of start_index: 1
number of end_index: 1
0
length1: 4 
length2: 5
legnth Sum: 9
```

output:

```
5 1 7 5 2 6 1 4 0 9 
K: 4
sum: 1
sum: 2
sum: 5
length of sums: 3
number of start_index: 3
number of end_index: 3
-------------Compute max subarray_sum length-----------------
2
length of sums: 2
number of start_index: 2
number of end_index: 2
1
length1: 3 
length2: 1
legnth Sum: 4
```

Any way I could make the solution better?..

Comment: It seems to me that your algorithm does not work. The only subarray in `[9, 9, 7, 0, 0, 9, 4, 2, 4, 5]` having `K=2`as the maximum element is `[2]`, so the result should be 2 and not 11.

Comment: @MartinR yes you were right.. I messed up the order of two lines.. It should be correct now.

Comment: Still looks wrong to me.  `[9, 9, 2, 0, 3, 6, 0, 1, 5, 6]` has no subarray at all with `K=4` as the maximum element.

Comment: @MartinR I am not sure I understand..  In the output example is `k=3`
And the subarrays are thus `{2,0,3}`  and `{0,1}` hence max sum is `2+0+3+1+0 = 6`

Comment: Sorry, my fault. But `{0, 1}` has the maximum 1 and not 3, so that does not count. – Does your code produce the expected results with all the test cases in https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/sum-of-lengths-of-non-overlapping-subarrays/0?

Comment: Obviously in the code you are summing elements of array, not lengths, so the code does not solve the stated problem at all

Comment: Ahh.. yes I have made an mistake, I am computing the sum of the subarrays, and not the length og the them.

Comment: So.... I hope i fixed it now @Srv19.  You were absolutely right, and I hope i got it now.  I hope any of you could comment on my solution..

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any of the unit tests.  In fact, the way the program is structured (with everything in `main()`) strongly suggests that there are no unit tests.  This immediately reduces confidence in the code.

I'd start by restructuring so we have a simple function to call.  I'll make it accept an iterator pair, to act like standard algorithms:

```
#include <cinttypes>

template<typename ForwardIterator, typename Value>
std::size_t total_length_of_segments_having_max_value(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const Value& value);
```

We can then write some tests:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v1{ 2, 1, 4, 9, 2, 3, 8, 3, 4 };
    auto const first = v1.begin();
    auto const last = v1.end();

    // start by testing an empty input
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUALS(0, total_length_of_segments_having_max_value(first, first, 2));

    TEST_ASSERT_EQUALS(5, total_length_of_segments_having_max_value(first, last, 4));
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUALS(0, total_length_of_segments_having_max_value(first, last, 10));
}
```

(I leave the implementation of `TEST_ASSERT_EQUALS()` as an exercise - or you can modify to fit your favourite testing framework.)

With the tests in place, we can write a suitable implementation and refine it as we improve the code, with confidence that we're not breaking anything that previously worked.

Answer (score 1):

Reuse the standard algorithms! It will give your code much more expressiveness, and they are very optimized. For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
template <typename Iterator>
int max_subsets_length_with_max(Iterator first, Iterator last, int k) {
    auto begin_subset = std::find_if(first, last, [k](auto&& elem) { return elem <= k; });
    if (begin_subset == last) return 0;
    auto end_subset = std::find_if(begin_subset, last, [k](auto&& elem) { return elem > k; });
    if (std::find(begin_subset, end_subset, k) != end_subset) {
        //std::cout << "subset [" << *begin_subset << " , " << *end_subset << "]\n";
        return std::distance(begin_subset, end_subset) + max_subsets_length_with_max(end_subset, last, k);
    }
    return max_subsets_length_with_max(end_subset, last, k);
}
```

Comment: Quick question. Why do you need to make the argument of the lamda functions auto&& and not just auto&?

Comment: @WooWapDaBug In the context of template deduction, `&&` is what is called a 'universal reference': it will be deduced as a lvalue reference (e.g `const int&`) if given a lvalue as argument, or a rvalue reference if the argument is passed by value or rvalue (e.g `int` or `object&&`). Basically the compiler chooses the right option for you.

Comment: But I don't get what's the point there. Isn't find_if passing things by value? can't you just do auto& to get it by reference? I think that the purpose is to avoid a copy, doesn't auto& achieve it? Sorry for my ignorance and thank you for the explanation

Comment: @WooWapDaBug No point here, you're right, just a good practice. `auto&&`does it always right, so why bother choosing the right signature by your self? In other places you could find iterators which don't return lvalue references, like `move_iterator`.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know that it always did it right. I'll use it from now on! thnx for the tip

Comment: So what would happened if I use auto& for move_iterator? I still don't get the point. I thought the universal reference where used when you need to do something different depending on whether you get an lvalue or rvalue. I think that reserving && for when you care about that makes your code say "here I care if it is lvalue or rvalue". What do you think? By the way, thnx for all the info

Comment: auto& can't bind to a rvalue reference, so it wouldn't compile I guess